# tuckey urlrewrite no query parameters

Tags: servlets, url-rewriting

I've searched everywhere and read every post on this here in StackOverflow, the result seems to be the same.

All I am trying to do is rewrite every HTTP url to a HTTPS one.  Pretty easy stuff but UrlRewrite does not seem to be working.

My urlrewrite.xml is as follows

```
  <rule>
<name>Redirect to HTTPS</name>
<condition operator="notequal" name="request-uri">https</condition>
<from>^(.*)$</from>
<to last="true" qsappend="true" type="permanent-redirect">https://%{server-name}%{request-uri}%{query-string}</to>
```

Is this a known issue and does anyone have a better recommendation on what the issue is ?